# Notifications for any window events

Tags: objective-c, macos

Currently I am using the following code to get notifications when applications are started or ended in OSX.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] addObserver: self
                               forKeyPath: @"runningApplications"
                               options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                               context: NULL];
```

This has worked really well so that my app is aware of the general state of the running applications in the system.  However now I'm wondering if I can go a level lower. What I would like is to be notified when any window in the system experiences a state change. If any window in the system is closed, minimized, resized, etc I would like my app to be notified.

Is this possible? I am under the impression that my application really can only know these things about the windows that I own. But I figured it couldn't hurt to ask here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I not sure if you can observe changes to windows, but you can get more specific information on windows (for all running apps, not just your own) by using either:

1. The assistive app (accessibility) APIs ([docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXModel/OSXAXmodel.html))
2. The private interface to the Core Graphics system ([docs here](https://code.google.com/p/undocumented-goodness/source/browse/trunk/CoreGraphics/CGSPrivate.h))

Comment: I was looking for something more like an asynchronous notification.  Rather than polling myself.

Comment: Thanks for the links though Wain.  Appreciate it.